# QTreeWidget and QFileSystemModel

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qfilesystemmodel

Please tell me how to connect to QFileSystemModel QTreeWidget simply function SetModel() not support QFileSystemModel but only QAbstractItemModel, but I need to work with files and for these purposes QAbstractItemModel not fit, I would like to open files in directories climb QTreeWidget.
Thanx

Comment: QFileSystemModel derives from QAbstractItemModel, what problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Use QTreeView, not QTreeWidget, with QFileSystemModel. QTreeWidget is for (simple) cases where you don't directly use a model but create the items one by one.

Comment: Prompt how to connect QFileSystemModel QTreeView example. I just can not imagine how. We have QFileSystemModel functions are not in QAbstractItemModel.

Answer (score 1):

`setModel` is a private function in QTreeWidget. To use it, you could create a custom TreeWidget class that inherits QtreeWidget and QTreeView, create a public function `setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model)` and in it call the QTreeView `setModel`function like so:

```
 TreeView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model){
      QTreeView::setModel(model); 
 }
```